# Making it easier to read page source in firefox

Tags: firefox, html

In firefox, to read the page source, I do Tools / Web Developer / Source. A pop up appears with the page source.  Sometimes this pop up will have massive amounts of white space making it very difficult to read. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **[View Source Chart](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/view-source-chart/)**

Am using this add-on on firefox 9, I can view HTML in a better look n feel.

Answer (score 1):

[This addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/view-formatted-source-format-s/) adds more color to the source code,not essentially removing space, but it makes firefox's source code page better.

P.S:-Chrome's view source is a lot better than FF

Comment: Thanks but not available for firefox 9

Comment: @dublintech It is easy to make an add-on compatible with firefox by changing the `<em:maxversion>` in the `install.rdf` if you like the extension.